# mongodb push to embedded array, values of document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, push

Hello i have this document

```
{
    name: 'name1',
    versions: []
}
```

and i want to update it to be

```
{
    name: 'name2',
    versions: [
        {
            name: 'name1'
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using nodejs and mongoose

Answer (score 1):

You should use $push. Suppose your using a schema named Person for your example. You should use this:

```
Person.updateOne(
    { _id: person._id }, 
    { $push: { versions: {name: 'name1'} } }
)
```

also if you have already selected the document you want and stored it as `person` you can use this snippet:

person.versions.push({versions: {name: 'name1'}})

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
doc.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { name: "name1"},
                    { "$push": { "versions": { name: 'name1' } } }

                )
```